# Why does UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity return an error about GUID being 32 bits?

Tags: c#

My application uses the `UserPrincipal` class to determine what groups a user belongs to and then uses that information to determine if a user is authenticated to use my application. Things worked just fine for while, but recently I've started getting an exception

> Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

When calling `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity`. It seems like the call is succeeding and the exception is being handled properly, but it makes me nervous that authentication is going to break suddenly in the future. I'm not explicitly creating the GUID anywhere, so I have no idea where the exception is coming from.

Comment: How is the call succeeding if you're getting an exception?

Comment: I have my debugger set to break on exceptions. The exception is being thrown somewhere in the framework code, but it's being handled there so it's not bubbling up the stack. Maybe that's the way it's supposed to work? I'm pretty sure it didn't work like this before though.

Comment: Probably - that's not an uncommon way to check for some condition - try it, if it throws an exception swallow it and do something else.

Comment: Can you tell _where_ the exception is thrown in the framework code? (and the stack trace from that point)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's most likely that an exception is being thrown somewhere deep in the Framework code that's trying to initialize some sort of security descriptor from an invalid GUID value.  If the framework is catching it and handling it internally I wouldn't worry about it.

Tracing through the Framework code, here is one likely place that it happens:

```
protected static bool IdentityClaimToFilter(string identity, string identityFormat, ref string filter, bool throwOnFail)
{
  if (identity == null)
    identity = "";
  StringBuilder filter1 = new StringBuilder();
  switch (identityFormat)
  {
    case "ms-guid":
      Guid guid;
      try
      {
        guid = new Guid(identity);
      }
      catch (FormatException ex)
      {
        if (throwOnFail)
          throw new ArgumentException(ex.Message, (Exception) ex);
        else
          return false;
      }
...
```

Notice that it *tries* to create a new `Guid`, and if it fails, an exception is thrown, but the code swallows it and just returns false

Comment: Yup, that's exactly where the exception gets thrown. Working backwards, I didn't start noticing until a few days ago when I installed .NET Reflector. I used reflector(like you did) to generate PDBs then step in until the exception happened. Not sure how Reflector caused me to be able to break on it in the first place when I couldn't pre-reflector. In any event, this seem innocuous. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

If you provide the IdentityType, it will not try to consider your value as a Guid, so it will not throw an exception

```
FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalEx), **IdentityType.SamAccountName**, identityValue);
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. Not sure why it all of the sudden started happening. Use to work just fine. But this was a solid fix.

Answer (score 2):

My debugging system suddenly started doing this out the blue and I couldn't figure out why. Turned out that when I'd deleted a .user file I seem to of disabled `Just My Code` debugging and this exception started getting broken into. So check your VS options around this area, you (probably) want this ticked:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Only below way worked for me.

```
var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
```